# Xamarin iOS: Detecting if vibration is available / supported on the device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin iOS I can get the device to vibrate using:

```
SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound();
```

However, this simply does nothing if the device does not support vibration, which is currently the case with iPAD devices.

Is there a way to **find if vibration is supported** on the device?

Comment: It seems Apple documentation doesn't talk about a method to check if current device supports vibration. However assuming that right now only iPhone can vibrate you can check on which device is running your app with `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom` and then perform different actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `TargetIdiom`:

```
if(Device.Idiom.Equals(TargetIdiom.Phone))
{
   // vibrate supported because only iPhone can vibrate
}
```

But please remember it is kind of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any thing in Ios to check if device supports vibration or not.  According to apple documentation, [kSystemSoundID_Vibrate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/ksystemsoundid_vibrate) (vibration) works only on iPhone -- not on iPod and not on iPad.

So you have to check if current device is iPhone to check if vibration is supported:

```
if(Device.Idiom.Equals(TargetIdiom.Phone))
{
   // you can play vibrate sound.
}
else
{
//play other sound
}
```